# DataAdapter.Update firing DeleteCommand

Tags: vb.net, gridview, dataadapter

I have this code:

```
Private Sub bbSaveloc_ItemClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles bbSaveloc.ItemClick
    gvLocations.CloseEditor()
    gvLocations.UpdateCurrentRow()
    'standorte speichern
    fb.Connect()
    fb.ReadyForData()
    fb.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_id", company_id)
    'evtl. vorhandene location_id-s holen
    fb.Command.CommandText = "select location_id from locations where company_id=@company_id order by location_id"
    Try
        fb.Datareader = fb.Command.ExecuteReader
    Catch ex As FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException
        XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        fb.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    If fb.Datareader.HasRows Then
        While fb.Datareader.Read
            fb.Dataset.Tables(0).Rows(index).Item(0) = fb.Datareader.Item(0)
            index = index + 1
        End While
    End If
    'insert
    fb.Command.Parameters.Add("@location_id", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.Integer, 0, "LOCATION_ID")
    fb.Command.Parameters.Add("@name", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.VarChar, 50, "NAME")
    fb.Command.Parameters.Add("@postal_code", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.VarChar, 10, "POSTAL_CODE")
    fb.Command.Parameters.Add("@road_nr", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.VarChar, 100, "ROAD_NR")
    fb.Command.CommandText = "insert into locations values ((SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR GEN_LOCATION_ID FROM RDB$DATABASE), @company_id, @name, @postal_code, " & _
                             "@road_nr)"
    fb.Dataadapter.InsertCommand = fb.Command
    If Not savefirst Then
        'update
        fb.Command.CommandText = "update locations set name=@name, postal_code=@postal_code, road_nr=@road_nr where location_id=@location_id and company_id=@company_id"
        fb.Dataadapter.UpdateCommand = fb.Command
        'delete
        fb.Command.CommandText = "delete from locations where company_id=@company_id"
        fb.Dataadapter.DeleteCommand = fb.Command
    End If
    fb.Dataadapter.Update(fb.Dataset.Tables(0))
    savefirst = False
End Sub
```

I have the following problem with this:

I insert a row in the gridview, then I save it -> ok.
I then modify some values of this row in the gridview, then I save it -> the row will be deleted and not updated as excepted.

I have checked the `RowState` of this row, it's modified. So I don't unterstand, why it deletes the row.

If I don't initialize the `DeleteCommand`, the update works as excepted.

**EDIT:**

I have now rewrote the code:

```
'standort datasource initialisieren
fb_loc.Connect()
fb_loc.ReadyForData()
'select
fb_loc.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_id", company_id)
fb_loc.Command.CommandText = "select * from locations where company_id=@company_id"
fb_loc.Dataadapter.SelectCommand = fb_loc.Command
Try
    fb_loc.Dataadapter.Fill(fb_loc.Dataset, "locations")
Catch ex As FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException
    XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    fb_loc.Close()
    Exit Sub
End Try
gcLocations.DataSource = fb_loc.Dataset.Tables(0)
'insert
Dim insert_command As New FbCommand("insert into locations values ((SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR GEN_LOCATION_ID FROM RDB$DATABASE), @company_id, @name, @postal_code, " & _
                         "@road_nr)", fb_loc.Connection)
insert_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_id", company_id)
insert_command.Parameters.Add("@location_id", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.Integer, 0, "LOCATION_ID")
insert_command.Parameters.Add("@name", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.VarChar, 50, "NAME")
insert_command.Parameters.Add("@postal_code", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.VarChar, 10, "POSTAL_CODE")
insert_command.Parameters.Add("@road_nr", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.VarChar, 100, "ROAD_NR")
fb_loc.Dataadapter.InsertCommand = insert_command
'update
Dim update_command As New FbCommand("update locations set name=@name, postal_code=@postal_code, road_nr=@road_nr where location_id=@location_id and company_id=@company_id", _
                                    fb_loc.Connection)
update_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_id", company_id)
update_command.Parameters.Add("@location_id", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.Integer, 0, "LOCATION_ID")
update_command.Parameters.Add("@name", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.VarChar, 50, "NAME")
update_command.Parameters.Add("@postal_code", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.VarChar, 10, "POSTAL_CODE")
update_command.Parameters.Add("@road_nr", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.VarChar, 100, "ROAD_NR")
fb_loc.Dataadapter.UpdateCommand = update_command
'delete
Dim delete_command As New FbCommand("delete from locations where company_id=@company_id", fb_loc.Connection)
delete_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_id", company_id)
fb_loc.Dataadapter.DeleteCommand = delete_command
fb_loc.Close()
```

Then the save method:

```
Private Sub bbSaveloc_ItemClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles bbSaveloc.ItemClick
    gvLocations.CloseEditor()
    gvLocations.UpdateCurrentRow()
    fb_loc.Dataadapter.Update(fb_loc.Dataset.Tables(0))
End Sub
```

Insert works, but f. e. the update don't. I get a dbconcurrency exception.

I assume, I should get the generated autoincrement values for the `location_id` back to the dataset. Because an update can't performed due to the lack of the `location_id` values. But how do I get back this values in the datatable?

Comment: Is it deleted from database ot only from the `Dataset`/`GridView`?

Comment: It isn't deleted nor from database, nor from Dataset/Gridview. I don't perform any delete operations. I just insert a row in the gridview, save it, then modify it, then save it again and after this save, the row is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You are using one command for the update and the delete command:

```
    'update
    fb.Command.CommandText = "update locations set name=@name, postal_code=@postal_code, road_nr=@road_nr where location_id=@location_id and company_id=@company_id"
    fb.Dataadapter.UpdateCommand = fb.Command
    'delete
    fb.Command.CommandText = "delete from locations where company_id=@company_id"
    fb.Dataadapter.DeleteCommand = fb.Command
```

So the last assignment "wins", the delete action.

Instead you need to create different commands for every action.